# How to calculate frequency of characters in a FASTA file in Perl

Tags: perl, printing, fasta

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of certain characters in a string from a file that is in FASTA format. So the file looks like this;

```
>label
sequence
>label
sequence
>label
sequence
```

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of specific characters (e.g G's) from the "sequence" strings.
After calculating that (which I have been able to do), I'm trying to print a sentence that says: "The percentage of G's in (e.g.) label 1 is (e.g)53%".

So my question really is, how do I do a calculation on the sequence strings and then name each one in its corresponding output by the label above it?

The code I have so far works out the percentage but I have no way of identifying it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict; 

# opens file
my $infile = "Lab1_seq.fasta.txt";
open INFILE, $infile or die "$infile: $!\n";

# reads each line
while (my $line = <INFILE>){ 
    chomp $line;

    #creates an array
    my @seq = split (/>/, $line);

    # Calculates percent
    if ($line !~ />/){
        my $G = ($line =~ tr/G//);
        my $C = ($line =~ tr/C//);
        my $total = $G + $C;
        my $length = length($line);
        my $percent = ($total / $length) * 100;

        #prints the percentage of G's and C's for label is x%
        print "The percentage of G's and C's for @seq[1] is $percent\n";
    }
    else{

    }
}

close INFILE
```

It spits out this output (below) when I'm really trying to get it to also say the name of each label that corresponds to the sequence

```
The percentage of G's and C's for  is 53.4868841970569
The percentage of G's and C's for  is 52.5443110348771
The percentage of G's and C's for  is 50.8746355685131
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to match your label and save that in a variable:

```
my $label;

# reads each line
while (my $line = <INFILE>){ 
    ...

    if ($line =~ />(.*)/){
        $label = $1;

    # Calculates percent
    } else{
        ...
        print "The percentage of G's and C's for $label, @seq[1] is $percent\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's fixed it perfectly. Thank you very much. I've spent a long time puzzling over that. :)

Comment: You did an excellent job posing your question.  Way to include all the needed information to make it easy to help.